# How to add JSON input in JAVA client

Tags: java, json, rest

I'm building a code to call a Post Web Service.
So I'm not able to add JSON input.
My JSON input must be this:

```
{ 
  "patientId": 13, 
  "timeType": 0, 
  "date": "19/08/2019", 
  "countryID" : "Central Europe Standard Time" 
}
```

This is my code:

```java
URL url = new URL("http://stgsd.appsndevs.com/AppCardioAPI/api/Resource/GetZephyrECGDataByPatientId");
HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
conn.setDoInput(true);
conn.setDoOutput(true);
conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
conn.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/json");
conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");


if (conn.getResponseCode() != 200) {
    throw new RuntimeException("Failed : HTTP error code : "
        + conn.getResponseCode());
}
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                        (conn.getInputStream())));
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
RRImportData parsed = mapper.readValue(conn.getInputStream(), RRImportData.class);
```

What can I do to set a JSON input object?

Answer (score 0):

Please do something like this:

```
    RRImportData data = new RRImportData();
    data.setPatientId("abcd");
    //set othe attributes..

    URL url = new URL(
            "http://stgsd.appsndevs.com/AppCardioAPI/api/Resource/GetZephyrECGDataByPatientId");
    HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
    conn.setDoInput(true);
    conn.setDoOutput(true);
    conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
    conn.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/json");
    conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");



    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    String payload = mapper.writeValueAsString(data);

    conn.setDoOutput(true);
    BufferedWriter wr = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(conn.getOutputStream()));
    wr.write(payload);
    wr.flush();
    wr.close();

    if (conn.getResponseCode() != 200) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Failed : HTTP error code : "
                + conn.getResponseCode());
    }
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader((conn.getInputStream())));
```

Here, first we are converting the POJO RRImportData to a String then we are writing it as a payload to your POST request. `BufferedReader br` can be used to read the response obtained from the server.

Comment: I am assuming RRImportData pojo represents the data that you want to post to your webservice, so line `mapper.writeValueAsString(data);` converts this data into a JSON string, and sends it to the server in form of POST request. let me know if something is still not clear .